# Playwright get_by_role using nth selector

Tags: python, css-selectors, playwright

I'm writing a Playwright test in Python. I have a table that I want to grab every row from to perform some actions within a for loop but I want to skip the first row.

I am able to grab every row within a table by doing something as simple as the following:

```
table = page.get_by_role("row").all()
for row in table:
    print(row)
```

But I want it to skip the first row. So I know the css selector for that is `:nth-child(n+1)` but I'm not sure how to use this in Playwright. I tried doing something like:

```
table = page.get_by_role("row:nth-child(n+1)")
```

But I got the error: `unexpected symbol ":"`

Then I tried:

```
table = page.get_by_role("row").nth("n+1")
```

But that also didn't work. Finally, tried this:

```
table = page.locator("[role=row]:nth-child(n+1)")
```

But I got the error: `ERROR test_table.py - TypeError: 'Locator' object is not iterable`

How do I properly query all the rows skipping the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than manipulating the selector, you simply start the for loop at the second element, like this:

```py
table = page.get_by_role("row").all()
# Using slice notation
for row in table[1:]:
    print(row)
```

Comment: yep, ended up doing this but was curious if there's anyway for Playwright to select out the first one in case I need to do something similar but more complex later

Comment: I am not able to test this myself at the moment, but maybe you could filter out first row like this? `table = page.get_by_role("row").filter(has_not=page.get_by_role("row").nth(0))`